# ubuntu 18.04 installation crashings

Tags: software-installation

why is it that when ever am installing some softwares like doker and etc my terminal downloads them but fails to install them fully at the last minute saying;==> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 1):

In `Synaptic`, go to the **Edit** menu and select **Fix Broken Packages**. Do this twice. Then click the **Reload** icon, and if any errors appear, you need to fix those, to help solve your problem.